# AngularJS - Diretivas: Element ou Atributo

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directives

Sou novo em angularJS e estou vendo a parte de Diretivas, e estou vendo que existe o restrict element e restrict attribute. Eu entendi o que cada um faz, porém não ficou claro quando devo utilizar um ou o outro, ou os dois?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você é livre para utilizar ambas quando bem entender, mas em alguns casos vale mais a pena utilizar ao invés do outro.

Diretivas como elemento é uma boa pedida quando você está trabalhando com trechos repetitivos de HTML que poderiam ser isolados por exemplo, mas nada o impede de utilizar diretivas como atributos para realizar o mesmo procedimento.

Diretivas como atributo é uma boa pedida para validações em elementos do tipo input por exemplo, mas nesse caso não seria possível fazer o mesmo através de diretivas como elemento.